# Shiny Title image seems unformatted

Tags: r, image, user-interface, shiny, navbar

I was working on a Shiny application, and instead of a title, I wanted to use an image. While the code did not raise any errors and shows the designated area for the image, the image doesn't show up.

Here is the code:

```
# header UI
ui <- navbarPage(title = div(img(src="/Users/atillacolak/Desktop/tafn_logo.png",
                                 height = 60,
                                 style = "margin-top: -14px; padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px")),
                 selected = "home",
                 theme = bs_theme(
                     bg = "white",
                     fg = "#ed7117",
                     base_font = font_google("Prompt"),
                     code_font = font_google("JetBrains Mono")),
                 fluid = TRUE,
                 home)
```

The result of this code is given in the image below.

[image: Resulting Image]

As you can see the image does not format. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the image available as a static resource to shiny's webserver.

Either you put the image in a `www` folder (subdirctory of your app folder) and set `src = "/tafn_logo.png"` or you use [addResourcePath](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/addResourcePath.html):

```
addResourcePath(prefix = "Desktop", directoryPath = "/Users/atillacolak/Desktop")
```

---

src using prefix:

```
img(src="Desktop/tafn_logo.png",
                                 height = 60,
                                 style = "margin-top: -14px; padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px")
```

See my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460159/display-pdf-file-which-isnt-stored-on-www-folder-inside-r-shiny-app/64462560#64462560).

Comment: adding a resource path worked, thank you